# How to properly send https request from reactjs to nginx/nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, axios

I am sending https requests from my front end reactjs to backend nodejs like this :

```
 axios
  .get("https://123.456.7.8/api/SWS")
  .then((response)=>{...})
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering if this is the right and securable way to perform this request?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Direct IP calls to your server or API endpoints are not safe, you should use a DNS service like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) to hide your real IP and use a domain.

This would also provide additional benefits like caching (optional), and DDoS protection.